# Can I clone an object if I have access only to its interface and is not serializable?

Tags: java

I have the interface of an object. I don't know if the implementation is serializable or not. Nor Cloneable.
And I don't have getters of object properties, actually, I don't know the properties either.

Can I still clone the object?
I mean, can I do something like:

```
public void copyMyObject(MyObject myObject){
    this.copyOfMyObject = ...//? can I make a deep copy?

}
```

I guess not...but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You might be able to hack your way around this by probing for various serialisation interfaces. But is this good code? No, it certainly isn’t. If your code needs to be able to copy an object, it should be supplied with all the necessary information to do so. Everything else is poor design and should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: yes, it's not indeed about good/bad. It's about my understanding of java. What I do if I need to save the state of this object? It is a non-solvable problem if I can not clone it?  So should I provide or ask for cloning ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well ... it depends.

You can serialize an object if the object's actual class implements `Serializable` ... and the rest<sup>1</sup>.  The actual type may be different to the (static) type of the variable where you are getting the object's reference from.

But if not, then you are not missing something.  Deep copying an object that doesn't implement its own deep copy methods, getters and setters, or some form of serialization, would involve some *extremely nasty* coding<sup>2</sup>.

You are better off designing your classes so that they can be serialized / cloned. Or, so that you don't *need* to clone them.

Note that there are a few Java classes that would be impossible to clone *correctly* even by "nasty" means.  Examples include `Thread`, `Socket`, `Class`, `ClassLoader` and some key `awt` classes.  So if your (hypothetical) application design depended on (say) being able to clone a running thread, that design would not be implementable.

---

<sup>1 - Instance fields that are not `transient` and not `null` need to be serializable as well.  And so on.

2 - For example, you could conceivably make use of abstraction breaking reflection and use of the `Unsafe` to replicate what the object serialization implementation does under the hood ... without the `Serializable` type check.  It is a bad idea though.</sup>